# Import data to MS SQL Server for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

I am running Visual Studio 2010. I do not have an SQL server license. All I have is what comes with VS2010. I have a large quantity of data in Access and Excel. Is there a way to convert these to an SQL format that is usable and save-able?

I have tried Access:

- upsizing wizard but it seems to require an full version of MS SQL.
- a third-party conversion utility but hit the same problem.
- using Access through the Entity Framework but it is both buggy and slow.

Comment: Pretty sure you can dump it in SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SQL Server Express its free and using Management studio you can import your data from different data sources like Excel and Access

download it here http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to upsize to SQL Server look into getting a SQL Server trial. You can get a 180 day trial here 
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/get-sql-server/try-it.aspx.

Your company may be eligible for software programmes such as WebsiteSpark and Bizspark which include a full licence for SQL Server for free*.

*read the product description before signing up.

Answer (score 0):

As Chase Florell says you should be able to do it with the free [express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx). If you need something more there's the [developer edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/developer.aspx) which is the same as the enterprise edition feature wise yet costs ~$45. With SQL Server 2012 out next month you might want to hold back on buying that though.

Comment: Just remember to always check the licensing terms before going live. The developer edition has licensing limitations that prevent you from legally using it to feed a production system. When you go live you'll need to use one of the full editions or the Express edition as appropriate.